# Create a contenteditable li tag with a delete button next to it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to build a `ul`, where each `li` is `contenteditable` and there is a delete button to the left of that `li`.
I tried doing this:

```
<ul id='list'>
    <li type='disc' id='li1' class='div' onkeydown='return func(event)' style='margin-left:0px;width:50%' contenteditable><button>delete</button></li>
</ul>
```

But the `button` becomes the `contenteditable` item and it's inside the `li` and not to the left.

Comment: `<li><span contenteditable>edit me</span><button>delete</button></li>`

Comment: seems simple enough to add a div and make button a sibling.

Comment: Applying `class="div"` to an `<li>` can be quite confusing in future... it's also a good practice to avoid inline styles as well as properties for styling purpose... [Why use CSS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Getting_started/Why_use_CSS). Where you trying to create something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/mrUVZ/1/)? if not comment below the answer, hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of directly editing the `<li>` , you could have a `contenteditable` child `<div>` and a button.

```
<ul id='list'>
  <li type='disc' id='li1' class='div' onkeydown='return func(event)' style='margin-left:0px;width:50%' >
    <div contenteditable></div>
    <button>delete</button>
   </li>
</ul>
```

So that you can position it easily relative to `<li>`, without it being edited, something like this [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mrUVZ/1/)

Answer (score -3):

I hope i understood your problem well.

[Please check the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3gU6v/)

```
<ul id='list'>
    <li type='disc' id='li1' class='div' onkeydown='return func(event)'  contenteditable>This is the sample text</li>
     <li type='disc' id='li1' class='div' onkeydown='return func(event)'  contenteditable>This is the sample text</li>
     <li type='disc' id='li1' class='div' onkeydown='return func(event)'  contenteditable>This is the sample text</li>
</ul>

#list {
    position:relative;
}
#list li {
    margin-left : 30px;
    line-height: 25px;
    margin-bottom:5px;
}
#list li:before {
    width:50px;
    line-height:25px;
    background:#ddd;
    content:'Delete';
    position:absolute;
    left:0px;
    text-align:center;
    border:1px solid #777;
}
```